# How can I fill an S-record with two byte values starting on even address boundaries?

Tags: c, linker, embedded

When I compile my code I eventually get [Motorola S records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SREC_%28file_format%29) (**a.mot**) with gaps (the whole address range is not covered by code and data).

I want to fill those gaps with the pattern `0x01 0x80`. However, it is important that all of the two-byte pairs must start at even addresses. `0x0180` is an opcode from my micro that I want to be executed if the PC reaches an address of unused flash area.

Before you start answering I'd like to tell you that **-repeat-data** in **srec_cat** has an issue:

- Given two sections e.g. **C** and **D** put one after another (**D** after **C**) in address space.
- Given that last byte of section **C** ends on address `0x76` and first byte of section **D** is on address `0x78`. In other words there is 1 byte long gap at address `0x77` between them.

Under such conditions, if I use **-repeat-data `0x01 0x80`** option, srec cat will fill that one byte with `0x01` and start filling following gap from `0x80`.

I do not know sizes of those sections because linker handles it.

Comment: Personally I would solve this with a quick Python script called as a post-link step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [srec_cat](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/) to create a file covering your required address range filled entirely with the 0x01 0x80 sequence aligned as required.

Then use srec_cat with the `-multiple` and `−disable-sequence-warning` options to "merge" the "filler" file with your application image file.  You should specify the filler file as the first file so that it is overwritten by the application data specified second.

It will issue many warnings, but it should work.

Comment: I thought of it but haven't tried it yet. I'll give this sollution a shot.

Answer (score 3):

I would write a simple parser in Windows working like this:

- The program creates a new s-record file based on the one you got from the compiler.
- Loop through the generated file and read two s-record lines at a time.
- If the line is an information line, S0, S9, S5 etc, just write it to the new file.
- If line 1 has an address + size smaller than the address on line 2, you have found a gap. (address1 + size1) < address2.
- Write line 1 to the new file.
- If you found a gap, write a line with your gap constants S1xx01800180 and so on. Calculate the checksum as you go.
- Write line 2 to the new file.

Comment: Does the s19 format require that the lines be in address order?

Comment: @Sam Skuce I'm not sure if it is actually required, but every tool I've seen place them in address order, particularly linkers. If you want to be 100% sure you could always sort the rows first, then apply the above algorithm.